# URL to open a CashApp payment?

Tags: payment, square

I'm building an app where I want users to be able click a link to open up CashApp (as well as various other P2P payment apps), as far along in the transaction as possible. My client doesn't want the app to actually handle the payments, just for it to forward along to a place to make the payment.

So, for example, I can go to `venmo.com/username` to open the Venmo app to a certain user's profile, which is basically enough for me. (anyone know how to include an amount or message in the url?)

But `cash.app/username` goes to a webpage that directs me to the App Store get the app, and doesn't even open the app on my phone if it's already downloaded.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##"This is actually quite simple with a universal link:

https://cash.app/$username/amount
The following example will open a cash app payment of $12.50 for the user with username 'helloworld':

[https://cash.app/$helloworld/12.50"##](https://cash.app/$helloworld/12.50%22##)

I also used the same format but instead of app I used me:

https://cash.me/$username/5.00/

And when i click on the button with the as anchored:
"href="https://cash.me/$username/5.00/">"

The phone with the APP opens the payment of $5.00 with the username and the person just needs to hit send.

Answer (score 6):

This is actually quite simple with a universal link:

```
https://cash.app/$username/amount
```

The following example will open a cash app payment of $12.50 for the user with username 'helloworld':

```
https://cash.app/$helloworld/12.50
```

Comment: I'm having issues with this. The amount does not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 3):

To pass info to Venmo app you can use:

```
venmo://paycharge?txn=pay&recipients=someone&amount=9.99&note=For%20Things
```

Comment: Do you know where this is documented? The developer SDK is gone and I don’t see this documented anywhere, but it seems to work at least right now.

Comment: It's not, but I've documented another way of doing this here: https://gabeoleary.com/posts/venmo-deeplinking-including-from-web-apps

Answer (score 3):

This is the url format for Venmo deeplinking:
`https://venmo.com/<USER_NAME_1>,<USER_NAME_2>...?txn=<charge|pay>&note=<NOTE>&amount=<AMOUNT>`

You can read more about the [url format for Venmo Deeplinking here](https://gabeoleary.com/posts/venmo-deeplinking-including-from-web-apps).

Answer (score 1):

At this time, the ability to integrate with Cash app or accept or send Square Cash payments aren't currently available for Square’s API.