# URL/Deeplink to send money using CashApp

Tags: payment, square, venmo

I am trying to integrate CashApp's P2P payment services for an  iOS app. I can't find any SDKs to make things easy online, so I've recently accepted that using deep-links might be fine for now.

I found this post [URL to open a CashApp payment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56828273/url-to-open-a-cashapp-payment)

which states that I can send:

`https://cash.app/$[username]/12.50`

to link a user + payment, but I can't seem to figure out the format to attach a note using the deep-link. I tried this and it works, but I can't seem to figure out how to add a pre-filled note. Any idea on how I can get this done?